# Worker not initialising Heroku+Sidekiq+Postgres+Rediscloud

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, sidekiq

I'm trying to initialize Sidekiq in a Heroku worker using:

```
if Rails.env.production?

  Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL'], size: 2 }
  end

  Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { url: ENV['REDISCLOUD_URL'], size: 10 }

    Rails.application.config.after_initialize do
      Rails.logger.info("DB Connection Pool size for Sidekiq Server before disconnect is: #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.pool.instance_variable_get('@size')}")
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection_pool.disconnect!

      ActiveSupport.on_load(:active_record) do
        config = Rails.application.config.database_configuration[Rails.env]
        config['reaping_frequency'] = ENV['DATABASE_REAP_FREQ'] || 10 # seconds
        # config['pool'] = ENV['WORKER_DB_POOL_SIZE'] || Sidekiq.options[:concurrency]
        config['pool'] = 8
        ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(config)

        Rails.logger.info("DB Connection Pool size for Sidekiq Server is now: #{ActiveRecord::Base.connection.pool.instance_variable_get('@size')}")
      end
    end
  end

end
```

but I get the following in my log:

```
2017-04-12T22:33:20.435939+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from crashed to starting  
2017-04-12T22:33:23.510593+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec sidekiq -e production -C config/sidekiq.yml`  
2017-04-12T22:33:24.049032+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from starting to up  
2017-04-12T22:33:26.528756+00:00 app[worker.1]: 4 TID-otpsq87bc INFO: Booting Sidekiq 4.2.10 with redis options {:url=>"redis://rediscloud:REDACTED@redis-14870.c1.eu-west-1-3.ec2.cloud.redislabs.com:14870", :size=>20}  
2017-04-12T22:33:27.606408+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: State changed from up to crashed  
2017-04-12T22:33:27.590348+00:00 heroku[worker.1]: Process exited with status 1  
2017-04-12T22:33:27.506096+00:00 app[worker.1]: I, [2017-04-12T22:33:27.505980 #4]  INFO -- : DB Connection Pool size for Sidekiq Server before disconnect is: 5  
2017-04-12T22:33:27.509172+00:00 app[worker.1]: could not connect to server: Connection refused  
2017-04-12T22:33:27.509174+00:00 app[worker.1]:     Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting  
2017-04-12T22:33:27.509175+00:00 app[worker.1]:     TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Does anyone have an idea what's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It is looking for Postgres on localhost:5432.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when trying to run Sidekiq on Heroku. I fixed it by adding `url: <%= ENV['DATABASE_URL'] %>` underneath `production:` in database.yml.